# how to get the updated model after the diagram change?

Tags: gojs

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("decision",
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
        new go.Binding("text", "text"),
        // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the Horizontal Panel
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
          { fill: "yellow", stroke: "lightgray" }),
        // define a horizontal Panel to place the node's text alongside the buttons
        $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
          $(go.TextBlock,
            { editable: true, font: "15px Roboto, sans-serif", margin: 5, textValidation: okName},
            //textValidation: okAnswer},

function okName(textblock, oldstr, newstr) {
    return true;
};
```

I am wondering how to get the newstr outside of the OkName function?I want to collect all the newstr.

Thank you!

Comment: Improve formatting

Answer (score 1):

Your `go.TextBlock` should have a two-way binding, so when the text is accepted (validation is successful) your text is saved to the model.

e.g.

```
new go.Binding("text", "text").makeTwoWay()
```

If you don't want the text to be saved to the model, you could save your `newstr` inside the validate function to an custom array or whatever you like.
You can also access the model data manually from your function with `textblock.part.data`.